# Angular 2: What's the purpose of styles.css?

Tags: css, angular

I'm building an Angular 2 app and wondering how best to do styling in a parent-child fashion. Similar to the Angular 2's 'Tour of Heroes' tutorial, I have a top level styles.css file. Each of my components also have an associated styleUrl pointing to a component specific css file.

I figured I could specify global options in the styles.css file, and overwrite them as needed through component.css files.Then I discovered Angular 2 components are 'view encapsulated', meaning that properties from styles.css cannot be overwritten by the component at all. You apparently can set 'view encapsulation' to none for certain components, but then that component's css properties contaminate other components. That's not what I want.

What exactly is the use of a styles.css file if it can't be overwritten anymore? Is there a way to still set css options globally and overwrite them in certain components?

**Example**: Plunker example of Angular 2 'Tour of Heroes':

[https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-6/ts/plnkr.htmlIn](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-6/ts/plnkr.html)

Inside styles.css one finds the 'master styles', including the h2 properties

```
h2, h3 {
  color: #444;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
```

The component 'heroes.component.html' includes a h2 title 'My Heroes'. Suppose I want to style this particular h2 title with a different color than the other h2's in my app. I could go into 'heroes.component.css' and specify:

```
   h2 {
      color: #999;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-weight: lighter;
    }
```

However the color property is NOT overwritten this way because of 'view encapsulation'. Is there a way to still locally overwrite a master style, without changing the color for any other h2 header?

Comment: Rather than giving descriptive notes, could you please tell us at which point you are facing issue in styles?

Comment: Added an Plunker example, does that help clarify it?

Comment: Your style.css would be for the wider page that may not consist of just angular components. You could have a fixed header for example that doesn't need to be an angular component. This would be styled in your global styles

Comment: @KoenDeCouck I overwrite the h2 color in the hero-detail.component.css and it works. The default style for h2 is in styles.css.

Comment: are you looking on correct component? I changed the h2 color in ....component.css and it changed the view.

Comment: Mm that's odd, the same behavior doesn't happen for me outside of Plunker. Will dig into this some more...